# Math operation with two different length arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, size

I have 2 arrays with different sizes like this :

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3];
```

I would like to do this :

```
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    console.log(array1[i] / array2[i]);
}
```

What can I do to get back at the beginning of array2 when array1.length > array2.length ?

In order to have : 1/2 - 2/2 - 3/3 - 4/1 - 5/2 - 6-3

I tried to put 2 loops but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulo to wrap around:

```
for(i=0; i< array1.length ; i++){
    console.log(array1[i] / array2[i % array2.length]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus operator to round the index of array. Modulus `%` will return the remainder after division, so using `anyNumber % arrLen` will always be less than `arrLen`.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3];
var firstArrLen = array1.length,
  secondArrayLen = array2.length;

for (i = 0; i < Math.max(firstArrLen, secondArrayLen); i++) {
  document.write('<pre>' + (array1[i % firstArrLen] / array2[i % secondArrayLen]) + '</pre>');
}
```

Comment: `firstArrLen == array1.length`. `i % firstArrLen == i` always.

Comment: @Amit Yes, that is added for flexibility, you can interchange the `array1` with `array2` and this will still work.

Comment: So at least use `Math.max(firstArrLen, secondArrayLen)` in the for condition. (But then it won't truly be compatible with OP...)

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions do the job well. I can propose using `map` for the first array to make the code look nice:

```
var result = array1.map(function(e, i) {
    return e + '/' + array2[i % array2.length];
});

console.log( result );  // ["1/1", "2/2", "3/3", "4/1", "5/2", "6/3"]
```

Replace string `'/'` with `/` (dividing operator) to get the actual values.

Comment: Why go through all that length? forcing pointless function calls, allocating and populating an array, GC...  ? It would make sense if there's a need to create a new array, but like this? if anything, `.forEach()`, but that too is overkill in my POV.

Comment: @Amit I assume the OP wants to use the values somehow, not only to output them to the console. If so, it can be worth using an array to store them, and `map` could be a nice alternative to `array.push()` and all other stuff.